# How important is the HCL for disks for RAID cards?

Tags: raid

I'm looking to get a [Highpoint Rocketraid 3560](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816115067) from newegg and attach 10 2TB drives to it.  However, on the [HCL](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/PDF/IOP%20Compatibility_List.pdf) of the 3560 on Highpoint's web site, it lists exact models of HD's that are compatible with it.

How important is this list? Only a few of the models are available on newegg, probably because the list is a few months old, and the [cheapest $99 samsung](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822152245) is not on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're buying a RAID card from an OEM (Dell, HP, etc) I've often seen them reject non-branded drives, or explicity state that your warranty is not valid whilst that drive is connected to the array.

That said, for generic cards (Adaptec, LSI, etc) I've never seen a drive be rejected just because it wasn't on the HCL.

I have seen drives rejected because:

- The were the wrong compatibility (LVD or HVD, SATA or SAS)
- They were larger than the largest drive size supported (a common situation if the controller is older and only has 48-bit addresses)

But not because they're not explicity on the HCL (after all, it would be impossible to keep the HCL up to date enough to accomodate every new model of HDD).

Depending on how picky the manufacturer is they may reject any warranty claims if the non-HCL drive is still attached to the array.

Comment: +1 Worth mentioning that Highpoint may not support any problems you have if the drives aren't on their HCL, just like most of the major OEMs wouldn't.